# Every Instance of my Psuedo class style works except in one section

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have a group of sections on a page where every section has to have its own color style. The links have to be the same color of the area, and I have a styling where I cannot seem to get the link to take the color style. It is replicated from the same exact rules of the others that DO work.

The page is on http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/09_01_13 and the area is the orange are under "Fictional and Informational Text" on the mid left. Again, this is the exact same code from the other's that do work. Thanks for taking a look.

This is my CSS:

Comment: .fictionText a:visited {
       color:#f58220 !important;
       font-size:18px !important;
       font-weight:bold;
       text-decoration:none;
}

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: sorry, but for some reason no matter what I did, stack overflow rejected my code (I pressed ctrl+K, and even indented everything 8 spaces). But any help to see what I might be missing is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the issue was a upper-case letter miss-matched. Problem solved. Sorry for the waste of time.